# Filtering specific column in list of dataframes with map by index in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes (test) with one column starting with the word "total_" (numeric), one with names, and one holding years.
I want to find the cases (names) where the total is missing in one specific year but is there in the next.

I experimented around with str_detec(names) and contains(), tries using the column index to adress the column with the "totals", tried to filter it by year and is.na() for the missings, but I cannot figure it out.

```
lapply(test, function(x) filter(x[[x]][,1], is.na(.) & year == 1820))

map(test, ~filter(.x, sum(is.na(.x)), year == 1820))

map(test, ~filter_at(.x, sum(is.na(starts_with("total")))))
```

I just cannot figure it out how to filter by index with multiple conditions and then use map or lapply.

Uhhh very bad example: (I know this is just three times the same dataframe, but it should do the trick).

```
year <- c(1820, 1821, 1822)
names <- c("A", "B", "C")

df <- data.frame(year, names)
df <- expand(df, year, names)

df$total_1 <- c(NA, 1,2, 1,2,3, NA, 2,3)

l <- list(df, df, df)
```

And here is what I want

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 9 x 3
   year names total_1
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1  1820 A          NA
7  1822 A          NA

[[2]]
# A tibble: 9 x 3
   year names total_1
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1  1820 A          NA
7  1822 A          NA

[[3]]
# A tibble: 9 x 3
   year names total_1
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1  1820 A          NA
7  1822 A          NA
```

Comment: can you share a reproducible example and the expected output? it would be easier to help you that way.

Answer (score 0):

So you cannot use the column name `total_1` directly since it can be anything which has the word `'total'` in it?

Maybe something like this help?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(l, ~.x %>% filter(if_any(contains('total'), ~is.na(.) & lead(!is.na(.)))))

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   year names total_1
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1  1820 A          NA
#2  1822 A          NA

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   year names total_1
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1  1820 A          NA
#2  1822 A          NA

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   year names total_1
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1  1820 A          NA
#2  1822 A          NA
```